# What is the dress that Islam has mentioned for males?

Tags: practical-islam, clothing

For every country, people believe their national dress is what is an islamic dress, so in Pakistan, people believe [Shalwar Kameez](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shalwar_kameez) is a dress that is right with Islamic custom and Saudia and other Islamic states think it is [Thawb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thawb). This makes Pant shirt a debatable question especially on Friday where every Muslim comes to offer Friday Salah.

From what I know, from belly button to your knees should be covered? But people debate pant shirt is a)It is western b) your body shape is prominent.

What is the dress in Islam for men especially when going for praying?

Comment: Islam didn't specify any.

Comment: @Medi1Saif but ppl make it so, that tight clothes like pants or jeans r too visible to see body shape, so one should wear Juba or Shalwar Kameez so body shape isn't visible.

Comment: What I mean is in Islam it is not said you must wear a Jilbab or whatever the ruling is that you shouldn't wear revealing and tight clothes. Some people never the less like to pretend that this kinds of cloths is sunnah which isn't true.